# onStartShouldSetResponder and onStartShouldSetResponderCapture - what is the difference? [React Native]

Tags: react-native, view, touch

I have read all the documentation about `onStartShouldSetResponder` and `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture`. As far as I read `onStartShouldSetResponder` is for passing true or false so the view can be touchable. But still I can't tell the difference. I am trying to make the view touchable with that method and it is not working.